# Linux C app runs out of memory

Tags: c, linux, out-of-memory

I am running the [word2phrase.c](https://github.com/travisbrady/word2phrase) using a very large (45Gb) training set. My PC has 16Gb of physical RAM and 4Gb of swap. I've left it train overnight (second time tbh) and I come back in the morning, to see it was "killed" without further explanation. I sat and watched it die, when my RAM run out.

I set in my `/etc/sysctl.conf`

```
vm.oom-kill = 0
vm.overcommit_memory = 2
```

The actual source code does not appear to write to the file the data, but rather keep it in memory, which is creating the issue.

1. Is the total memory (RAM + SWAP) used to kill OOM? For example, if I increase my SWAP to 32Gb, will this stop happening?
2. Can I force this process to use SWAP instead of Physical RAM, at the expense of slower performance?

Comment: if 100% accuracy isn't important then you couldn't you break your set up into 10 chunks and compile the results manually?

Comment: @GradyPlayer I may have to if increasing SWAP doesn't solve this.
Unfortunately, this requires that I do online training, which may not be possible (I don't know how exactly the network model works).

Comment: @Alex - A potential issue occurs if memory is constantly allocated and freed. The virtual pages end up with unusable gaps. Environments like Microsoft's .net framework occasionally pause a process and repack memory pages to avoid this issue. I don't know what the equivalent is for Linux, and this may not be the reason that word2phrase is running out of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q: Is the total memory (RAM + SWAP) used to kill OOM?**

Yes.

**Q: For example, if I increase my SWAP to 32Gb, will this stop happening?**

Yes, if RAM and swap space combined (48 GB) are enough for the process.

**Q: Can I force this process to use SWAP instead of Physical RAM, at the expense of slower performance?**

This will be managed automatically by the operating system. All you have to do is to increase swap space.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the first question, yes.

Second question: 
*Can I force this process to use SWAP instead of Physical RAM*

linux dictates how the process is running, and allocate the memory appropriately for the process. When the threshold gets reached, linux will use the swap space as a measure.

Increasing swap space may work in this case. Then, again, I do not know how linux will cope with such a large swap, bear in mind, this could decrease performance dramatically.

Best alternative thing to do is split up the 45GB training set to smaller chunks.